# Are there any indications that the hat polykite or spectre appear as aperiodic structures in materials?

Tags: group-theory, material-science, physical-chemistry

It is known that certain aperiodic structures appear in quasichrystals. For instance, Daniel Schechtman and Ilan Blech discovered that the aluminium-manganese alloy Al$_{6}$Mn has no translational periodicity. This marked an important turn in the study of chrystallography.

I wonder whether the recently discovered aperiodic structures consisting of only one tile - the [hat polykite](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~csk/hat/) and the [spectre](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~csk/spectre/) - have appeared in the study of materials. To date, I haven't found any sources that indicate this is the case. My knowledge of the field is limited, however, as I have an academic background in mathematics.

> **Question**: Are there any indications that the hat polykite or specte appear as aperiodic structures in materials?